# trouble with my first ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https, letsencrypt, cloudflare

i'm struggling to get my first ssl certificate to work (but i seem to be at least recieving my certificate).

an example of some output from my docker-compose up is below

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7$ sudo docker-compose up
Starting traefik ... done
Starting doom    ... done
Attaching to traefik, doom
traefik    | time="2023-04-09T20:04:31Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."

doom       | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
traefik    | time="2023-04-09T20:04:38Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"tgmjack.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [tgmjack.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[tgmjack.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Cannot negotiate ALPN protocol \"acme-tls/1\" for tls-alpn-01 challenge\n" rule="Host(`tgmjack.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=doom@docker

traefik    | time="2023-04-09T20:04:40Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"tgmjack.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [tgmjack.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[tgmjack.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Cannot negotiate ALPN protocol \"acme-tls/1\" for tls-alpn-01 challenge\n" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=doom@docker rule="Host(`tgmjack.com`)"

....... skip a bit ....

traefik    | time="2023-04-09T20:04:47Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"tgmjack.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [tgmjack.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[tgmjack.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Cannot negotiate ALPN protocol \"acme-tls/1\" for tls-alpn-01 challenge\n" routerName=doom@docker rule="Host(`tgmjack.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

traefik    | time="2023-04-09T20:04:48Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"tgmjack.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [tgmjack.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[tgmjack.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Cannot negotiate ALPN protocol \"acme-tls/1\" for tls-alpn-01 challenge\n" ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=letsencrypt.acme routerName=doom@docker rule="Host(`tgmjack.com`)"
```

according to chat gpt

*"It seems that there is an issue with obtaining an ACME certificate for the domain "tgmjack.com". The error message suggests that there is a problem with negotiating the ALPN protocol "acme-tls/1" for the tls-alpn-01 challenge, which is part of the certificate issuance process. This could be due to a configuration issue with the ACME provider or with the domain's DNS settings. There are multiple error messages indicating the same problem with obtaining the certificate, so it may be worth investigating the root cause of the issue further."*

but i seem to have my certificate. as shown here in some output from my cmd line here.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7$ cd volumes
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7/volumes$ dir
traefik
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7/volumes$ cd traefik
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7/volumes/traefik$ dir
acme  logs
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7/volumes/traefik$ cd acme
ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:~/doom 7/volumes/traefik/acme$ dir
acme.json
```

so.... i have my certificate according to the above?

i got the example for my docker-compose.yml from here

https://greenfrognest.com/LMDSTraefikProxy.php

leading me to use the following

```
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command:
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=tgmjackcroc@gmail.com  # replace with your email
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=acme/acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./volumes/traefik/acme:/acme
      - ./volumes/traefik/logs:/logs

  doom:
    build: ./doom_dj/doom
    container_name: doom
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.doom.rule=Host(`tgmjack.com`)  
      - traefik.http.routers.doom.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.doom.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.http.services.doom.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

below is some evidence of stuff ive done on cloudflare

1. my dns section
2. ssl settings
3. edge certificates
4. my rules section

[evidence of what i did on cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTzGY.png)

what might be the problem here? whats should i try?

how might i zoom in on the problem better? prove things 1 way or another so i can start ruling stuff out?

Comment: Letsencrypt, when used on Linux (at least outside of docker) are saved under `/etc/letsencrypt/live`. There you should see a name which is likely your domain name. In that folder you'll see a `README` and a few `.pem` files (in my case, 4 of them). What you've shown above is probably some setup file.

Comment: 1) when i go into my etc/letsencrypt folder i only have renewal-hooks , no live folder

ubuntu@ip-172-31-93-63:/etc/letsencrypt$ dir
renewal-hooks
...
2) are you sure what youre saying isnt only true if i didnt specify the volumes location stuff in my docker-compose?
...
(i really dont know myself just trying to replicate what i did before)

Comment: ok, yeah

apparently cloudflare doesnt do alpn certificates. so its not there. 

do you know any cloudflare alternatives that do handle alpn tls certificates?